# Invalid object using WITH common table expression

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, try-catch

I am trying to use With in stored procedure

```
    USE [BusOprtn]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddRepairedStock]

     @RepairedItems [dbo].[RepairedItems] readonly


    AS
    BEGIN 

    declare @productNo bigint,@productManufacturer bigint

      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      begin try
      begin transaction
      UPDATE [BusOprtn].[dbo].[RepairItem] SET [ReturnedQuantity] = rdi.ReturnedQuantity,[AmountPaid] = rdi.AmountPaid,[ReturnDate] = rdi.ReturnDate from [BusOprtn].[dbo].[RepairItem] as ri inner join @RepairedItems as rdi on ri.id=rdi.id;

     ;with y as (
     select [PartUsedId],rdi.[ReturnedQuantity] from [BusOprtn].[dbo].[RepairItem] as ri inner join @RepairedItems as rdi on ri.Id=rdi.id 
     ), x as (
     SELECT  [PartNo] ,[ManufacturerId],[ReturnedQuantity] FROM [BusOprtn].[dbo].[PartUsed] as p inner join y 
     on p.id = y.PartUsedId
     )


      UPDATE [BusOprtn].[dbo].[ProductMaster] SET   [RepairedStock] =( [RepairedStock]+x.[ReturnedQuantity]) from [BusOprtn].[dbo].[ProductMaster] as pm inner join x on x.[PartNo]=pm.Id;
      UPDATE [BusOprtn].[dbo].[ProductStockManufacturer] SET  [RepairedCurrentStock] = ([RepairedCurrentStock]+x.[ReturnedQuantity]) from [BusOprtn].[dbo].[ProductStockManufacturer] as pm inner join x on x.[PartNo]=pm.[ProductNo] and x.[ManufacturerId]= pm.[ManufacturerId];

      commit transaction
        end try
        BEGIN CATCH
        declare @ErrorMessage nvarchar(max), @ErrorSeverity 

int, @ErrorState int;
    select @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Line ' + cast

(ERROR_LINE() as nvarchar(5)), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), 

@ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
    rollback transaction;
    raiserror (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
        END CATCH
END
```

When i execute above command it executes successfully. But when i try to call stored procedure at runtime it gives error

```
`Invalid object name 'x'.

Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.`
```

Earlier problem was with sub query as it not allowed with "WITH" so tried using another temp table `y` but error continued. I refereed [Allowed Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) for allowed items in WITH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the second update statement where you are using the CTE `x`

The scope for a CTE is one statement so `x` is only visible for the first update.

To fix this you can either duplicate the code for the CTE before the second update or you can use a temp table (or table variable) to capture the output from `x` and use the temp table in both your update statements instead of the CTE.

With a different formatting of the code this is easy to see.

First update statement:

```sql
with y as 
(
  select [PartUsedId],
         rdi.[ReturnedQuantity] 
  from [BusOprtn].[dbo].[RepairItem] as ri 
    inner join @RepairedItems as rdi 
      on ri.Id=rdi.id 
), x as
(
  SELECT [PartNo],
         [ManufacturerId],
         [ReturnedQuantity] 
  FROM [BusOprtn].[dbo].[PartUsed] as p 
    inner join y 
      on p.id = y.PartUsedId
)
UPDATE [BusOprtn].[dbo].[ProductMaster] 
SET [RepairedStock] = ([RepairedStock]+x.[ReturnedQuantity]) 
from [BusOprtn].[dbo].[ProductMaster] as pm 
  inner join x 
    on x.[PartNo]=pm.Id;
```

Second update statement:

```sql
UPDATE [BusOprtn].[dbo].[ProductStockManufacturer] 
SET  [RepairedCurrentStock] = ([RepairedCurrentStock]+x.[ReturnedQuantity]) 
from [BusOprtn].[dbo].[ProductStockManufacturer] as pm 
  inner join x 
    on x.[PartNo]=pm.[ProductNo] and x.[ManufacturerId]= pm.[ManufacturerId];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use SQL Server Profiler (`Service` menu in MSSMS). There you can find what query *exactly* received. Maybe something is different.

Hope it will help.